# git undelete remote branch

Tags: git, branch, undelete

I had my local directory on the `develop` branch, and I wanted to checkout the `remotes/origin/foo/bar` branch. Thanks to being an idiot with my bash command history, what I actually did was this:

```
git branch -a
```

(Note that, the remote branch doesn't exist locally yet)

```
git fetch
git branch -a
```

(Note that, the remote branch indeed exists locally now)

```
git branch -r -d origin/foo/bar
```

Stop everything, because I know what I just did.

If needed, I do indeed have other systems available, that had the remote branch checked out and fully updated. Those systems have not been touched since the remote deletion. And I can guarantee that no other developers have done a fetch or pull.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't deleted anything on your remote. Just your local reference to it. Assuming that the "server" still has it, just running `git remote update origin` should bring the reference back.